# Shopping Cart design interview

Tags: java

I was asked a question during interview. Goal is to design system according to described steps. Perform step 1, then improve design taking step 2 into account.

What would be the correct design/approach for this?

**Step 1: Shopping cart**

You are building a checkout system for a shop which only sells apples and oranges.

- Apples cost 60p and oranges cost 25p.
- Build a checkout system which takes a list of items scanned at the till and outputs the total cost
- For example: [ Apple, Apple, Orange, Apple ] => £2.05
- Input is a list of strings

**Step 2: Simple offers**

The shop decides to introduce two new offers

- buy one, get one free on Apples
- 3 for the price of 2 on Oranges
- Update your checkout functions accordingly

Comment: I'd recommend writing your own solution and posting this question to CodeReview.stackexchange.com. It's not really suited to SO answers, you'll get far better answers there. :)

Comment: The question is very broad, with any number of "correct" designs and approaches.  There is no canned/stock/absolute answer.  The interviewer wanted to see how you work and how you think:  begin describing how you would approach the problem and the things you would need to consider in your design.

Comment: Hmm. I see. SO likes O(1) question/answer mapping

Comment: I have my own solution, but as you know they never tell you what didn't work for them. Though I will hear design approach implementation, stick to interfaces or something else to see a range, will see if someone will show up.

Answer (score -5):

If you want to design anything, the bootstrap is a web page what have many designs, but you must have a call link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Paste this link in the HTML>head

Comment: Its about system design. Which is not same as styling of page.

Comment: Totally irrelevant answer